# How to unhide Developer in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2, developer-mode, merge-css, minified-js

**Hi, I am not able to view developer in**

[image]

Store > Configuration > Advance > ??Developer?? is missing.

**What should we do to unhide the Developer section in Magento 2?**

I was looking for Minify Js and CSS option.

Comment: Your admin user does not have enough permissions.

Comment: Are you administrator privilege user?

Answer (score 2):

can you check mode if production then you can change mode to developer after showing

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant Patel, Please explain more about deploy:mode:set developer How to do this, I can access FTP but not sure about deploy

Comment: Go to app/etc/env.php and changed mode to developer https://www.screencast.com/t/5XDkMwtqywBL

Answer (score -1):

That's great, Let me try this.

[image]

Please check if this is correct.

I am still not able to see Developer in admin side. Do I need to clean cache? or refresh cache management.

Comment: hi please check